# Yii CCheckBoxColumn how can get id of checked column on a CGridView

Tags: php, yii

I have `CGridView` with `CCheckBoxColum`:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id' => 'documento-financeiro-grid',
    'dataProvider' => $provider,
    'filter' => null,
    'columns' => array(
        array(
            'id' => 'autoId',
            'class' =>'CCheckBoxColumn',
            'selectableRows' => '50',
            'checked'=>'alert('
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'id',
            'htmlOptions' => array('style' => 'width: 50px;'),
            'headerHtmlOptions' => array('style' => 'width: 50px;'),
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'numero',
            'htmlOptions' => array('style' => 'width: 60px;'),
            'headerHtmlOptions' => array('style' => 'width: 60px;'),
        ),
 ),
));
```

And I want show a dialog window when a row was checked, but I need to know what id of row was checked, someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to write what your code would look like.

You have to write some javascript that listens on the `change` event for your checkboxes (this event gets triggered when checkboxes get clicked on).

I've used a jquery selector to select the checkboxes based on what column they are in (this is because your grid may have other columns with checkboxes - we don't want to touch those).

In my example code, I've assumed your checkboxes have ID's that begin with `documento_financeiro-grid_c0` (this is the ID Yii gives them by default). Please change that if this isn't the case.

The row id is stored in the variable `item_id` and variable `item_checked` contains `true` if your checkbox was checked and `false` if it was unchecked.

```
$('#documento-financeiro-grid input[id^=documento-financeiro-grid_c0]').change(function() {
    var item_id = $(this).val();
    var item_checked = $(this).prop('checked');

    if (item_id === "1") {
        console.log('top checkbox was clicked on');
    } else {
        console.log('ID was'+item_id);
    }
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you help, but when I try this the event was not trigged, I try this: `$("#documento-financeiro-grid input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {` but the event not trigged too. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Are you sure the javascript code is being added to your page? Try adding something like `console.log('foo')` to your javascript code and see whether you can see that in your browser console. This is just to see whether the code is actually being loaded.